# autocompletetextview filter dropdown data

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete, simplecursoradapter

I have created custom autocompletetextview component.In that I have also created a populateList method for autocompletetext data.

```
final com.example.admin.ctronhot.autocomleteclass autocomplete=(com.example.admin.ctronhot.autocomleteclass)findViewById(R.id.abc);
    final String sql="select * from g101 where desc LIKE '%" + autocomplete.getText().toString() + "%'";
    final String[] mfieldsa=new String[]{"desc"};
    final int[] mobjectsa=new int[]{R.id.desc};
    autocomplete.populateList(R.layout.brow_g101_layout, sql, "desc", aa, mfieldsa, mobjectsa, order.this);
```

**It is showing drop down data but it is not filtering data as per typed in autocomplete.getText.toString()**

Here is my function populateList

```
    public void populateList(Integer _layoutfile, final String sqlaa, String mfieldget, com.example.admin.ctronhot.autocomleteclass mauto,
                         String[] mfields, int[] mobjects, Context mcontext) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(co.mcurd_data_path_, null);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlaa null);
    int layoutResourceId = 0;
    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpeCursorAdapter(
            mcontext,        // Context
            _layoutfile,    // Row layout template
            cursor,                    // cursor (set of DB records to map)
            mfields,        // DB Column names
            mobjects                // View IDs to put information in
            , layoutResourceId
    );
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            final int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("desc");
            return cursor.getString(colIndex);
        }
    });

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence description) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(co.mcurd_data_path_, null);
            Cursor managedCursor = db.rawQuery(sqlaa, null);

            return managedCursor;
        }
    });
    mauto.setThreshold(1);
    mauto.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Please help Me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in `runQuery` you are not using the `description`

Comment: in argument sqlaa contains sql query with where clause

Comment: do you know what is `description` in `runQuery`?

Comment: no, but if I write "select * from g101 where desc LIKE '%" + autocomplete.getText().toString() + "%'" instead of sqlaa in runquery it is working .

Comment: so use `description` in the query, it just works, why do you think it is passed as the parameter?

Comment: how could I write that? please suggest me some

Comment: do you know how to write sql select statement?

Comment: I have to use populateList method to all of my autocomplete objets so I need sql query as parameter

Comment: so just use `description` in your `rawQuery` call

Comment: can you give me sql select query for this

Comment: select * from something where desc like %description%

Comment: where to write this in class or activity

Comment: in `runQuery` you are not using the `description`

Comment: you are saying that write sql select in runQuery but my sql select is not there it comes through argument/parameters

Comment: can you just `Log.d` the value of `description` and see the logcat?

Comment: I have also noticed that it is displaying edittext value

Comment: so use it in your `rawQuery` then... what is not clrear?

Comment: it is showing blank results

Comment: can I pass value of Charsequece description in another activity

Comment: Cursor managedCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from g101 where desc LIKE '%" + description + "%'", null);

Comment: It is working in this way, But I want to write this query in my activity from where I am calling this autocomplete.populateList(R.layout.brow_g101_layout, here want to write query, "desc", aa, mfieldsa, mobjectsa, order.this);

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: lets see, If I wrote select query in runQuery then I have to write separate runQuery for each autocompleteviewtextview object. I am creating one method populateList for all autocompleteviewtextview objects.

Comment: so read **carefully** `rawQuery` docs, pay special attention on second parameter

Comment: where can I get it's docs

Comment: you dont know where to get android SDK docs?

Comment: hi jon skeet are you there? Please answer me

Comment: did you read `Cursor rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)` documentation? do you now how to use `selectionArgs` parameter?

Comment: Yes. There is class system in .net or visual foxpro.i doing like that.i have previously programming in visual foxpro.

Comment: I want to create only one custom components of autocompletetextview and use it in all over apps autocomplete objects so i need to do it with parameters passsing

Comment: so do that: just add a `sql` parameter in `populateList` method and inside `runQuery`  make `selectionArgs`  based on `constraint` and return the Cursor from `rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs)`

Comment: Problem has solved perfectly by your suggestions Very very thanks.thank you.you are so useful.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help.